# Create custom labels under a graph

Tags: vb.net, graph, label, series

I've got different series in my project that I'd like to show in my graph. N element of each series are related to one "parent element", and we've got M parent elements to show up. I'm trying to underline this relationship creating a "label" under the x-axis.

[Here is what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcJsO.png)

The Red,Yellow And Blue are the 3 series I'd wish create and as you can see they could have a different amount of point related to the "item". The label I'm trying to create is the one under x axis.

I'm trying to understand how to dynamically create a "label" or "customlabel" item with a simple border propriety under the x-axis. The related code should allow me to set up the initial value and last one, but I'm unable to setup the border.

```
  Dim myLabel As New DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel

    myLabel.FromPosition = 0
    myLabel.ToPosition = 5
```

Comment: Could someone point me to a tutorial or a guro able to explain me what to do ?